# if else list comprehension in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

Lets say I have a dictionary,

```
pets ={'Dogs' : np.array(['Oscar','Coco']), 'Cats' : np.array(['Sylvester']), 'Parrots' : np.array([])}
```

Next I want to form a new dictionary where I want to replace the empty array with None but keep the rest of the values as it is

```
petsNew = {k : None if v.size == 0 else k : v  for k,v in pets.items()}
```

However, this results in a syntax error, any ideas why?

Output required:

```
petsNew
{'Dogs' : np.array(['Oscar','Coco']), 
'Cats' : np.array(['Sylvester']), 
'Parrots' : None}
```

Comment: `petsNew = {k : None if v.size == 0 else v for (k, v) in pets.items()}`

Comment: `k : None if v.size == 0 else v` - you can't have the `k :` twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the tertiary condition syntax is `x if y else z`, the `k :` is part of the dictionary comprehension, *not* the tertiary condition.  So when the `k:` is part of the `else` condition it makes for invalid syntax.

The fix is therefore remove the extra `k :` within your tertiary condition:

```
petsNew = {k: None if v.size == 0 else v for k, v in pets.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary comprehension only has separate expressions for key and value. `k : v` by itself isn't a valid expression, so it can't be nested inside an if-then-else expression either. You'd need to wrap key and value each in a separate if-then-else expression for it to work.

Luckily, as the key is the same in both cases, you just need to make an expression for the value.

```
{k : (None if v.size == 0 else v) for k,v in pets.items()}
```

Comment: Note: if the key needs to be also a separate condition, it is possible to put two tertiary condition in both sides of the `:` like so: `{k if k in 'ace' else k.upper(): v if v % 2 else v*10 for v, k in enumerate('abcde')}`.  The results would be: `{'a': 0, 'B': 1, 'c': 20, 'D': 3, 'e': 40}`